# MariaDB Docker cannot connect using local domain as host

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have an issue with my dockerized MariaDB. It happens when I try to connect to MariaDB.
Example with PhpMyAdmin: If I put MariaDB docker server's IP & port in the PHPMyAdmin config file (see picture), PhpMyAdmin can connect without any issue. But if I put the server hostname and the port, it doesn't connect. MariaDB doesn't accept the hostname. One of the problems I have is that the server change the IP, so it's an issue if I am not using the hostname. I checked that etc/mysql/my.cnf has #Bind 127.0.0.0 in docker container with #.
Also, the hostname works well in the browser (windows or linux).
Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT
I am also attaching the container info from Portainer.
[image: I am adding the container info.]

Thanks

[image]

Comment: how do you create your docker container? If you run `docker ps` do you have something like `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp` under PORTS?

Comment: I use portainer, but yes in portainer, I have Port configuration 
0.0.0.0:3306  3306/tcp

Comment: Also network config is set in bridge mode

Comment: Are you using docker-compose ? If yes , please paste your docker-compose. Let we know

Comment: I don't use docker compose, I use portainer to create the containers from docker hub images